# Pass function as a reference vs declaring inside addeventlistener performance difference

Tags: javascript

I need to know is there any difference in terms of performance micro-optimizations if i declare function inside Addeventlistener?

Is function recreated every time event listener is fired?

```
function fun(){
    a += b;
}
element.addEventListener("click",fun);
```

Vs

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    a += b;
});
```

Comment: No. The event listener is created once in both examples.

Comment: @InSync but some of post in google and even chatgpt says that function is recreated every time event listener is called

Comment: Which post(s)? Could you give a link?